# How to replace a tag %%article%% by letter a

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({'text': ['I have %%article%% car', '%%article%%fter dawn', 'D%%article%%t%%article%%Fr%%article%%me']})
```

I am trying to replace `%%article%%` by letter `a`  to have as output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'text': ['I have a car', 'after dawn', 'DataFrame']})
```

I tried to create a `dict ={'%%article%%':'a'}` and then:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].map(dict)
```

But it's not working, it returns `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When passing a `dict` to `Series.map`, it uses table lookup so that only elements that exactly match `'%%article%%'` will be replaced by `'a'`.

An example from [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
>>> s = pd.Series(['cat', 'dog', np.nan, 'rabbit'])
>>> s
0      cat
1      dog
2      NaN
3   rabbit
>>> s.map({'cat': 'kitten', 'dog': 'puppy'})
0   kitten
1    puppy
2      NaN
3      NaN
```

An element with something like `'ccat'` will not be replaced. Instead, you can use a function to replace them:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['I have %%article%% car', '%%article%%fter dawn', 'D%%article%%t%%article%%Fr%%article%%me']})
>>> df.text = df.text.map(lambda i: i.replace('%%article%%', 'a'))
>>> df
           text
0  I have a car
1    after dawn
2     DataFrame
```

But the better is probably [Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
>>> df.replace('%%article%%', 'a')
           text
0  I have a car
1    after dawn
2     DataFrame
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['text'].str.replace('%%article%%', 'a')
```

Output:

```
0    I have a car
1      after dawn
2       DataFrame
Name: text, dtype: object
```